# UILocalNotification with custom sound only works on iOS 6.1 and iOS 7.1, not iOS 7.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uilocalnotification

I have developed an application where the user can select from a few custom notification sounds to sound. These notifications will either be shown in-app through a simple AVPlayer or through a UILocalNotification when the app is not in the foreground. The foreground alert ofcourse always works. The background alert did not work on one of my testers' iPhone 4S.

At first I thought it was a configuration problem on his phone but we couldn't find anything. When I started digging deeper into the problem I discovered he was running iOS 7.0.4. I tried to run the application on an emulator running iOS 7 instead of iOS 7.1 and I did not have any sound with a UILocalNotification neither. When I tried iOS 6.1 in my simulator there were no problems at all again. My hardware device running iOS 7.1 did not reproduce the problem either. The message and logo always show no matter what version, it's just the sound that's missing.

Then I thought the problem might be related by the fact that it wasn't running in the foreground thread of the app. performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: did helped neither.

This is the relevant code:

```
+ (void)minimizedAppAlarm:(Settings *)settings;
{
    UILocalNotification* notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.alertBody = NSLocalizedString(@"WAKE_UP", @"Wake up!");
    if (settings.playSound)
    {
        notification.soundName = @"somefile.mp3";
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it has to do with setting the badge number using the following call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:number];
```

Currently I am not sure what exactly happens but I do a countdown from ten to zero when the app is minimized and perhaps setting the badge to zero just before the alarm it blocks.

I have been running my app without these lines of code and it's firing the background notifications in every version. Note that I have been testing this app on lower version in the simulator and I did need to do the following before I noticed any changes

- Remove the app from the home screen
- Reset contents and settings

Since the simulator does not have any settings for notifications I guess somehow 7.0 sets the notifications muted if I used setApplicationIconBadgeNumber. For now I can continue finishing the app without the countdown feature but I will continue testing so I know for sure I only need to disable iOS 7.0 or the problem exists on most versions if I start a version of the app that directly changes the badge number.